# PARALLEL_ENABLE - when not to use it

Tags: oracle, plsql, parallel-processing

It is recommended to declare Oracle PL/SQL functions as `PARALLEL_ENABLE` when they can be parallelized, so the DBMS knows it can run the function in parallel.

But when is a function parallelizable? Or rather: when is it not?

Let's look at an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_country_name(p_country_code VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 
  PARALLEL_ENABLE
AS
  PRAGMA UDF;
  v_country_name country.name%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT name INTO v_country_name
  FROM country
  WHERE code = p_country_code;
  RETURN v_country_name;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RETURN NULL;
END;
```

The function selects the country name for a given country code, e.g. 'France' for 'FR'. I made it UDF, because I will mainly use it in SQL queries, and I made it parallel enabled, because, well, then it works better in `select /*+parallel(4)*/ get_country_name(code) from ...` - is this what it means? Or what else?

And why can I declare this function `PARALLEL_ENABLE`? What exactly makes it parallelizable? Can I just declare all my functions `PARALLEL_ENABLE`? Then I should, shouldn't I? Or are there circumstances that would prevent that? What would keep a function from being parallelizable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PARALLEL_ENABLE` is somewhat of a mystery. Oracle's documentation is very unclear. It is certain that you don't need it in parallel query (PQ, parallelizing of `SELECT` blocks) - parallel slaves will happily execute your scalar functions in the `SELECT` clause without being marked as `PARALLEL_ENABLE`.

One place it definitely does make a difference is with parallel DML (pdml) when using *non-pure* functions. Per the docs:

> Enables the function for parallel execution, making it safe for use in
> concurrent sessions of parallel DML evaluations.

It actually only needs this when the function is non-pure, and not at all when it's regular PQ. Here's a demonstration, arbitrarily using a large table I have named "snapshot".

This performs the function call serially and effectively disables pdml from working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myname(in_value IN integer)
  RETURN number 
AS  
  PRAGMA UDF;
BEGIN
  RETURN SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID'); -- makes it non-pure
END;
  
create table tmp1 (col1 integer)  ;

alter session enable parallel dml;

insert /*+ append parallel(x,32) */ into tmp1 x 
select /*+ parallel(32) full(s) */ myname(snapshot_id) from snapshot s
```

Execution plan:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                          | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT                   |          |   344M|  2302M| 10381   (1)| 00:00:01 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  LOAD AS SELECT                    | TMP1     |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX COORDINATOR                   |          |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   3 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)             | :TQ10000 |   344M|  2302M| 10381   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   4 |     OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING |          |   344M|  2302M| 10381   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|   5 |      PX BLOCK ITERATOR             |          |   344M|  2302M| 10381   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|   6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL            | SNAPSHOT |   344M|  2302M| 10381   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Hint Report (identified by operation id / Query Block Name / Object Alias):
Total hints for statement: 1 (U - Unused (1))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
   0 -  INS$1 / X@INS$1
         U -  parallel(x,8)
 
Note
-----
   - Degree of Parallelism is 32 because of hint
   - PDML disabled because function is not pure and not declared parallel enabled
```

As you can see, the `LOAD AS SELECT` operation comes above/after `PX COORDINATOR`, so no PDML. The actual insert step is serialized.  The plan comments even give us an example of why. Of course this makes sense: depending on which PX slave executes it, the result will be different (since I'm returning the SID of the executing process). Oracle doesn't want us to get different results depending on whether PX is involved or not or how rows are distributed, but this would cause that.

So, we have to swear on our graves that this is really what we want. Now add `PARALLEL_ENABLE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myname(in_value IN integer)
  RETURN number PARALLEL_ENABLE
AS  
  PRAGMA UDF;
BEGIN
  RETURN SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID');
END;

insert /*+ append parallel(x,8) */ into tmp1 x select /*+ parallel(32) full(s) */ myname(snapshot_id) from snapshot s
```

Execution plan:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                          | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT                   |          |   344M|  2302M| 10381   (1)| 00:00:01 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                    |          |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)              | :TQ10000 |   344M|  2302M| 10381   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    LOAD AS SELECT (HYBRID TSM/HWMB)| TMP1     |       |       |            |          |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING |          |   344M|  2302M| 10381   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      PX BLOCK ITERATOR             |          |   344M|  2302M| 10381   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|   6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL            | SNAPSHOT |   344M|  2302M| 10381   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Note
-----
   - Degree of Parallelism is 32 because of hint
```

Now `LOAD AS SELECT` comes below/before `PX COORDINATOR`, so we are in full PDML mode here and that insert will go a lot faster. Adding `PARALLEL_ENABLE` to that scalar function made it possible to use it in a PDML operation.

If the function were *pure*, then the `PARALLEL_ENABLE` clause isn't necessary. PDML will work just fine without it, because Oracle knows the result won't change regardless of how rows are distributed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myname(in_value IN integer)
  RETURN number
AS  
  PRAGMA UDF;
BEGIN
  RETURN in_value*100;
END;
```

Plan:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                          | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT                   |          |   344M|  2302M| 10381   (1)| 00:00:01 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                    |          |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)              | :TQ10000 |   344M|  2302M| 10381   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    LOAD AS SELECT (HYBRID TSM/HWMB)| TMP1     |       |       |            |          |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING |          |   344M|  2302M| 10381   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      PX BLOCK ITERATOR             |          |   344M|  2302M| 10381   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|   6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL            | SNAPSHOT |   344M|  2302M| 10381   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Note
-----
   - Degree of Parallelism is 32 because of hint
```

Still in PDML mode, but without `PARALLEL_ENABLE`.

There are other uses for it. The docs discuss it in connection with pipelined functions, particularly with ref cursors, but I've never definitively seen it working. I routinely add it to my pipelined functions, but my execution always show serialized output which are then distributed to the first PX slave set. I have never seen the output itself parallelized.

Perhaps someone else can throw their experience in here who has managed to get it working with *pipelined table functions*.

Comment: Thank you for this extensive explanation. I gather that almost every function is parallelizable and declaring them all `PARALLEL_ENABLE` can speed up inserts and updates where the functions are used. If I don't use them in DML, then I have no benefit, but no penalty either. Your example with a SID access has definitely helped me understand the matter and pointing out that this is about DML has made it very clear what this is allabout. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`PARALLEL_ENABLE` *used* to be more important and was needed for any kind of parallel operation. The current affects are much smaller, and they are well described by Paul's answer.

Per the [11.2 Database PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_function.htm#CIHIHEIB), `PARALLEL_ENABLE` was needed to allow the function to ever run in parallel:

> parallel_enable_clause
>
> Indicates that the function can run from a parallel execution server
> of a parallel query operation. The function must not use session
> state, such as package variables, as those variables are not
> necessarily shared among the parallel execution servers.

The [12.2 Database PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/PARALLEL_ENABLE-clause.html) now explains that the clause applies mostly for DML operations. I think the last sentence from the below quote is a documentation bug; the author added the first sentence limiting the scope of this clause, but forgot to modify the original sentence that implied the clause applies to all parallel operations.

> PARALLEL_ENABLE Clause
>
> Enables the function for parallel execution, making it safe for use in
> slave sessions of parallel DML evaluations.
>
> Indicates that the function can run from a parallel execution server
> of a parallel query operation.

I don't have an 11g instance for testing, but I think I can remember having to add `PARALLEL_ENABLE` in many functions, even if there was no DML involved. And based on my testing, your function used in a query should run just as fast with or without `PARALLEL_ENABLE`.

Comment: Thank you for adding this answer, Jon. So nowadays the situations where we benefit from declaring a function `PARALLEL_ENABLE`, are comparably few, but if I even see only a small chance that my function may be used in a DML context I'd better use this clause to help the DBMS to parallelize the writing operation. Thank you.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I just tested on 9.2, 10.2 and 11.2 and found the same behavior - `PARALLEL_ENABLE` was never necessary for a scalar function to be called by PX slaves in a PQ query. Plus it didn't complain about the function looking at session state either (not even in 9i where I had to query v$mystat instead of sys_context). So I think the documentation has aalways been wrong about this.

Comment: That's interesting - I recall a case once where a virtual column that used a user-defined function prevented DBMS_STATS from using the specified DOP because it was not parallel enabled, but I forget the details. I'm pretty sure this was at least 12.1, and I don't think it included a query or sys_context etc but I'll see if I can check. There was another case where a lookup function cached values in a PL/SQL collection, and when it wasn't parallel enabled the PX slaves couldn't see the cache.